# How to format a number with comma?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, database, sql

Currently, I am using this query

```
SELECT top 10 
snt.Domain, 
count(*) AS DomainCount 
from 
_Sent snt 
group by snt.Domain 
order by count(*) desc
```

The data type of "DomainCount" is number and the data is displaying as "1234567"

How to format a number with comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a field to your report table - DomainCountWithCommas (Text 50) and run this horrible SQL...

```
SELECT top 10 
    snt.Domain,
    COUNT(*) AS DomainCount,
    REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(count(*) AS MONEY),1), '.00','') AS DomainCountWithCommas
FROM
    _Sent snt 
GROUP BY
    snt.Domain
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: I tried the above query and getting query syntax error - `Incorrect syntax near ')` . I am also not sure if above query includes * (star) or (1)?

Comment: This worked for me `REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(count(*) AS MONEY),1), '.00','') AS DomainCountWithCommas`

Comment: @l-k Thanks. I've updated the answer to remove the syntax error and incorporate your feedback. Much appreciated. On the "*" vs "1" question... They both amount to the same thing and it's largely  a matter of personal preference which one you use. There are some urban myths out there that state that "1" jumps the step where the Query Optimizer needs to go to the data dictionary to read the structure of the table being queried. It's not true. The results and execution plans are identical. You can use whichever you feel more comfortable with.